# Apache POI - PPTX to PNG skewing text and shapes

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm currently using Apache POI 3.16 to take a PPTX slide deck and transform it into a set of .png thumbnails. I modeled my PPTX to PNG function closely off of a few pre-made solutions I found across the web.

I'm having issues primarily with text being rendered about 6-8pt larger in the resulting PNGs. Additionally, complex shapes such as hexagons are extremely skewed when being rendered. Can anyone suggest any fixes? I'm mostly concerned with the font sizes being much larger.

Here is my code, commented for readability:

```
  public List<String> generatePNGThumbnails(String inputFilePath) {
    // List of the thumbnail paths that will be returned.
    ArrayList<String> thumbnailFilePaths = new ArrayList<>();

    // Open the file.
    File inputFile = new File(inputFilePath);

    try {
      // Open the PPTX as an XMLSlideShow.
      XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(OPCPackage.open(inputFile));

      // Output size for rendered images.
      Dimension pageSize = slideShow.getPageSize();
      int width = (int)(pageSize.width * TRANSFORMATION_SCALE);
      int height = (int)(pageSize.height * TRANSFORMATION_SCALE);

      // Get a list of the slides in the PPTX.
      List<XSLFSlide> slides = slideShow.getSlides();
      for (int i = 0; i < slides.size(); i++) {
        XSLFSlide slide = slides.get(i);

        // Create a new image object and prepare it for rendering.
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();

        // Set graphics rendering options and draw the PPTX slide to the image.
        graphics.setRenderingHint(
          RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
          RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
        );
        graphics.setRenderingHint(
          RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, 
          RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY
        );
        graphics.setRenderingHint(
          RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, 
          RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY
        );
        graphics.setRenderingHint(
          RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, 
          RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC
        );
        graphics.setRenderingHint(
          RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, 
          RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON
        );
        graphics.setRenderingHint(
          RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION,
          RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY
        );
        graphics.setColor(Color.white);
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        graphics.scale(TRANSFORMATION_SCALE, TRANSFORMATION_SCALE);

        // Draw the slide to the 2DGraphics.
        slide.draw(graphics);

        // Save the newly created image to the local disk.
        String slideFileName = "slide" + i + ".pptx";
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(slideFileName);
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", fileOutputStream);

        // Add the output file path to the list of paths to be returned.
        thumbnailFilePaths.add(slideFileName);

        // Clean up before proceeding to the next slide.
        graphics.dispose();
        img.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
      }
    } catch (InvalidFormatException | IOException e) {
      // ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure about the text parts yet, but I've provided a patch for the skewed preset shapes yesterday - see [#61119](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61119)

Comment: @kikiwings - thanks for your reply, I've reverted to 3.9 for the time being to fix the shape issue. However, text is being outputted larger still. Do you think this has to do with the font sets I'm using? FreightSansLFPro, etc... Thanks!

Comment: if you can share that PPTX, please open a bugzilla entry for [POI / SL Common](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI&component=SL+Common), I will have a look onto it. Using 3.9 in a production environment to parse arbitrary OOXML files (like PPTX) is simply a bad idea ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share any of the test data I've been using. Perhaps I can make a test slide this afternoon. Thanks for the offer.

We are developing this feature with the assumption that any version of POI is not intended for mission critical features, nor will ever produce a thumbnail that is identical to the input slide. That being said, I've landed on version 3.12 and have getting pretty good results. But when I make the jump to 3.13, thats where shapes begin to break down and text even larger than 3.9.

Comment: I'm not sure, if I have the same understanding about mission criticalness, but you might want to have a look at the [CVE list](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-22766/Apache-POI.html) and decide, if you know where your files come from ...

Comment: @kikiwings - Is there anyway I can remove unused Slide Master Layouts programatically? I have a slideshow with a single slide and a ton of unused Layouts in it's Master. When I delete those unused layouts in Powerpoint, the file goes from 20mb to 500kb.

Comment: there's no convenience API for that use case. You'd need to update the PackageRelationships yourself - somehow similar to XMLSlideShow.removeSlide(int) - this will be a bit of trial and error, because you need to make sure, that all references are removed. Usually you compare your programmatic result (i.e. the xml contents) with a file manually edited in Powerpoint